# VBA Print Specific Sheet not the Active Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, forms, button, printing

I have a print button on a form that will bring up the Print dialog box, and if I print, it will print the active sheet. Is it possible for me to assign the printing to a hidden sheet. Let's say "Sheet17". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub PrintButton1_Click()

Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show

End Sub
```

This is the code I currently have, works fine. I would just like to print a specific sheet.

Comment: Unhide the sheet, print and then hide it again.

Comment: Wording issue: The word "hidden" has a specific meaning in Excel. In your question, I think what you mean is a sheet that is not currently the active sheet. It is in a sense "hidden", but as long as you can see its tab, it's not considered hidden, just not visible. To make a sheet hidden in the proper sense, you'd have to right-click on the tab of a sheet and click "Hide".

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to print hidden worksheets in Excel, whether using VBA code or manually. Please try it.

```vb
Private Sub PrintButton1_Click()
    Dim ShtStatus
    With Sheets("Sheet17")
        ShtStatus = .Visible
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        .PrintOut copies:=1, Collate:=True
        .Visible = ShtStatus
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible for print dialog box to open before printing? Currently the above code will just automatically print the document. I'd like printing options to appear before the printing. Thanks

Comment: Please try `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show`